# Smooth click zoom I/O for THREE JS on transitions

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hy, i`m trying for quite a while now to animate a transition between scenes in THREE js, i have managed to clear the scene. and recreate the next one, however the transition towards each other is really painstacking, i have created 2 functions:

```js
function zoomInTransition() {
    var zInMin = 15;
    for (camera.fov; camera.fov > zInMin; camera.fov-=3) {
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
}

function zoomOutTransition () {
    var zOutMax = 70;
    for (camera.fov; camera.fov < zOutMax; camera.fov+=3) {
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
}
```

I run each function like so :

```js
function buttonReaction(){
    for (var i in objects) {
        switch(objects[i].name) {
            case "door_1":
                zoomInTransition();
                Start(room2);
                zoomOutTransition()
                break;
            case "door_2":
                zoomInTransition();
                Start(room1);
                zoomOutTransition()
                break;
            default: 
                console.log("default");
        };
    };
}
```

However i never manage to make the zoom tranzition smooth, it iterates too fast for the projection matrix updates to display. I`m running out of ideas... Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit late, but ...
You can create a helper function "transition" that will call small amounts of zoom until you reach the zoom(level) you wanted. for instance, if you want to zoom(20), then you call transition that will call 10 x zoom(2) very quickly one after another, which will create an illusion of smooth transition

```
//zoom function with transition
function zoomIn() {
    if(camera.fov > minZoom) {
        dom.zoomOut.css('opacity',1);
        transition(cameraZoomIn,20);
    }
    if(camera.fov-20 <= minZoom){
        dom.zoomIn.css('opacity',0.2);
    }
}

//zoom function with transition
function zoomOut(){
    if(camera.fov < maxZoom) {
        dom.zoomIn.css('opacity',1);
        transition(cameraZoomOut,20);
    }
    if(camera.fov+20 >= maxZoom){
        dom.zoomOut.css('opacity',0.2);
    }
}

//small amount of zoom
function cameraZoomIn(quantity){
    camera.fov -= quantity;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

//small amount of zoom
function cameraZoomOut(quantity){
    camera.fov += quantity;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

//Create a transition for the movement func (go left, up, zoom,...) where func must move with amount quantity
function transition(func, quantity) {
    var intervalTime = 15;
    //We make a small version of the same movement : move 1/10 of the original quantity every intervalTime
    var interval = setInterval(function(){func(quantity/10)}, intervalTime);
    //We stop doing the movement when we have done 10 times the small movement
    setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(interval)}, intervalTime*10)
}
```